# How to combile variables in Apache Velocity template engine?

Tags: plugins, velocity, confluence

I define 2 variables, baseURL and imageName.

And the actually image url is the combination of baseURL and ImageName.

For example, baseURL is "http://www.abc.test" and imageName is "Hello.jpg".

How to display the "http://www.abc.test/Hello.jpg" by baseURL and imageName variables?

Comment: Does `${baseUrl}/${imageName}` solve your problem or do you want to save the combined name inside a variable? Does `baseUrl` has a slash at the end? If you use your template for an action there is a "global variable" ${req.contextPath} which provides the baseUrl + contextPath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write

```
$baseURL/$imageName
```

in your template, for instance:

```
<img src="$baseURL/$imageName"/>
```

If you want to concatenate those two variables in another variable, do:

```
#set($url = "$baseURL/$imageName")
```